# how to display pdf reader module in drupal?

Tags: drupal, pdf-reader

ive installed the pdf reader in drupal and enabled it, then what comes next?it does not appear on BLOCKS or anywhere?what should i do? I need to make a pdf viewer site or ebook reader running locally(localhost).Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you use that plugin http://drupal.org/project/pdf_reader .
On that page you can read:

> PDF Reader will render your entity file fields with the selected PDF renderer.

and

> **Usage**
>   Create or attach an existing file field into an Entity then select the display options to be PDF Reader.

So you have to make new content type (or use existing one) and attach file field to it, then when asked about display options of that field (I don't remember if it will ask you about it by default or you have to edit it after it's added) choose PDF Reader. Then you will be able to make new node of that content type containing that field and upload your PDF creating it. When it's done, you should be able to see PDF embedded on your node page.

For more information:
Creating new Content Type: http://drupal.org/node/774728

Fields: 
    http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui
    http://drupal.org/node/774742
    http://drupal.org/node/774798
    http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field